# C# extension of Enumerable not working

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to add an extension to Enumerable class. but it seems that the extension FindEven() is not picked by the C# compiler. When I build, the compiler spit error :

```
CS0117 'Enumerable' does not contain a definition for 'FindEven'
```

Here is my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  static public class Program
  {
    static IEnumerable<int> FindEven(this IEnumerable<int> array, Func<int, bool> predicte)
    {
      foreach (var n in array)
      {
        if (predicte(n))
        {
          yield return n;
        }
      }
    }
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int[] numbers = new[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

      var result = Enumerable.Select(Enumerable.FindEven(numbers, n => n % 2 == 0), n => n);
      foreach (var output in result)
        Console.WriteLine(output);

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Anything I did incorrectly here?

[edit]

What I am trying to do here is to see how the 'where' statement in the following LINQ works by making my own version of 'Where', which in this case is 'FindEven' (not a good name I have to admit).

```
var result = from element in numbers
where element % 2 == 0
select element;
```

I think if I replace 'FindEven' by 'Where' which is defined in Enumerable[from metadata]... It should be the way LINQ works. But I just can not get the code compiled.

Thanks

Comment: BTW any1 has an idea that how comes I need 1500 reputation to create an 'extension' tag?

Comment: For data quality really - it stops 'just anyone' from creating tag after tag after tag.

Comment: Just replace `Enumerable.FindEven` with `Program.FindEven` or call it like an instance member function `numbers.FindEven`. Please notice that there is an existing extension method that does exactly what you did called `Where`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to do, but for 'Where', it can be called by Enumerable.Where. By some reason, the way I add extension is not right. So the Enumerable class does not think there is an extra method in the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per your edit, it seems you're trying to add your `FindEven` function to the `Enumerable` class, but that won't work. When you're calling `Enumerable.Where`, you're not calling an extension method, you're calling an actual static method that's defined in `Enumerable`. You can't extend that class that way, because extension methods can't extend static methods, that's not what they're for. They extend instance methods.

The equivalent in your code of calling `Enumerable.Where` is calling `Program.FindEven`. That's where the static method is defined. The magic of extension methods is having both `Where` and `FindEven` available for an instance of `IEnumerable<int>`, regardless of where they're defined.

**Pre-edit**

From the way you call the method, you seem to believe that the extension method adds a new static method to the `Enumerable` class. It doesn't work that way. The extension method you defined will "add" the method to any *instance* of `IEnumerable<int>`, so your code will look like this:

```
var result = numbers.FindEven(n => n % 2 == 0);
```

Note, though, that your `FindEven` doesn't actually FindEven - it just queries using the provided predicate, meaning it's exactly the same as the built-in LINQ `Where` function. A proper FindEven method would be:

```
static IEnumerable<int> FindEven(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    return source.Where(n => n % 2 == 0);
}
```

This will return a lazily-evaluated `IEnumerable<int>` containing only the even numbers.

Also, your external `Select` method does nothing - it just maps every integer to itself, meaning it returns an enumerable that's completely equivalent to its input.

Comment: I did not make my point clear, sorry, I added an [edit] section. Thanks

Comment: The reason I trying this because this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FupRSJe-cc0&index=6&list=PL90AF0EFFEF782D27 It seems it could be done.

Comment: From skimming over the video, it seems it shows you how to add an extension method in your own class, similar to how `Enumerable` defines its own extension methods. The confusion stems from the fact that the code shown uses the non-extension-method syntax (`Enumerable.Where(list, func)`) rather than the extension syntax (`list.Where(func)`).

Answer (score 1):

When you define an extension method, you have to call it as it was a member function of your `this IEnumerable<int> array` parameter

simply replace your call with

```
var result = Enumerable.Select(numbers.FindEven(n => n % 2 == 0), n => n);
```

Also note that you created an extension method for `IEnumerable<int>`, not for `Enumerable` class

Comment: Isn't `Select` an extension method too? You told him that he has to call it like a member function. I'm not sure that this is correct. You can call every extension method like a normal static method. The only mistake he did was to call it on `Enumerable`. He should call it on `Program`.

Comment: I did not make my point clear, sorry, I added an [edit] section. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per your edit, you can use Where function.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    static public class Program
    {
        static public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

            var result = numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 0);
            foreach (var output in result)
                Console.WriteLine(output);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not make my point clear, sorry, I added an [edit] section. Thanks